# Compact Lie group action on non-Hausdorff (but CGWH) space with Hausdorff quotient

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, lie-groups, separation-axioms

Assume that we are in the following situation: a compact Lie group $G$ acts on a compact space $X$ which is not necessarily Hausdorff. $X$ is assumed to be compactly generated and weakly Hausdorff, though. The quotient space $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

Does this imply that $X$ is Hausdorff? I do not think this is true but I'm also unable to find a counterexample since I cannot come up with a non-Hausdorff space that admits a non-trivial $G$-action in the first place.

The reason I'm thinking about this is the following: If the $G$-action on $X$ was additionally free (and $X$ was Hausdorff), then $X$, being compact and Hausdorff, would be completely regular, and hence the quotient map $X \to X/G$ would be a fiber bundle by a result of Bredon. I'm also interested in whether $X \to X/G$ is a fiber bundle if $X,G,X/G$ are as above and the $G$-action is free.

Comment: $X$ weakly Hausdorff: all images of compact Hausdorff spaces in $X$ are closed (implies $T_1$: points are closed). Compactly generated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space

Comment: One reason it may be hard to think of an example by hand is because you assume the quotient is Hausdorff, and then compactness of $G$ implies that each orbit subspace must be Hausdorff. With a Hausdorff "base" and Hausdorff "fibers," non-Hausdorffness in the "total space" has to come from something weird.

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole: Thanks, I had not realized that the weak Hausdorff property on $X$ is sufficient to have Hausdorff orbits until now. I agree that this makes a potential example even less likely to be found.

Comment: It seems that a weakly Haudorff first-countable space is Hausdorff, so the answer is affirmative for first-countable spaces $X$. By the way, what is the answer for finite acting group $G$?

Comment: @TarasBanakh why does WH + first-countable imply Hausdorff? I wasn't able to find this statement, maybe you're confusing this with the fact that every first-countable space is compactly generated (see Strickland's notes, for example).

Comment: @TarasBanakh Unfortunately, I don't know the answer for finite groups. If $G$ is finite, any orbit subspace of $X$ is discrete, but this does not really help to separate two points of the orbit.

Comment: @AlexanderKörschgen To prove that a first-countable WH-space is Hausdorff, assume that two distinct points $x,y$ cannot be separated by open neighborhoods and choose decreasing countable neighborhood bases $(U_n)_{n\in N}$ and $(V_n)_{n\in N}$ at $x,y$, respectively. For every $n\in N$ choose a point $x_n\in U_n\cap V_n\setminus\{x,y\}$. Then the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ converges to $x$ and $y$ simultaneoulsy. Since the set $K=\{x\}\cup\{x_n\}_{n\in N}$ is a continuous image of the compact Hausdorff space $\{0\}\cup\{2^{-n}:n\in N\}$, it is closed in the WH-space, a contradition.

Comment: Taras's argument shows more generally (1) WH implies US (unique sequential limits), (2) US + first-countable imply Hausdorff.  Also see https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000099 for example.

Answer (score 1):

How about $X=\{ a,b,x,y\}$ with nontrivial open sets $\{a,b\}$ and $\{ x,y\}$ and $G= Z/2$, discrete. 
The action exchanges $a$ with $ b$ and $x$ with $y$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, the space $X$ is not weak Hausdorff. If we endow $K := \{c,d\}$ with the discrete topology, $K$ is compact Hausdorff. However, the map $K \to X$ given by $c \mapsto a, d \mapsto x$ is continuous while its image $\{a,x\}$ is not closed in $X$.